# Changing ssh port on fedora-26

Tags: ssh, port, fedora

I vimed into

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I edited

```
#Port 22
```

to

```
#Port 922
```

After I restarted httpd.

```
service httpd restart
```

However, ssh still only works on -p22.

How do I edit the ssh config file to change the ssh port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, but also had to:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 922
```

In order to get semanage

```
dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils
```

Then restart sshd

```
systemctl reload sshd.service
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comment marker (#) before the statement.

```
Port 922
```

and you have to restart sshd, not httpd.

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I restart ssh. I was restarting httpd asuming that would cascade into ssh.

Comment: [root@fedora-e1 ~]# service ssh restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart ssh.service
Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.

Comment: Why should this cascade from httpd to ssh? Try ˋsshdˋ or check with ˋsystemctl | grep sshˋ to find the correct name.